# Gitlab with SQL Server as database source configuration handling

Tags: sql-server, docker, gitlab, configuration-files

I have a self hosted gitlab on ubuntu machine. I configure a linux container for it to run `runner`. Now, I am trying to write a configuration for my dotnet project to  run unit test on this setup.

I get configuration to run dotnet application without database, and only part I got stuck is that I cannot get Database to load or connect through my test environment.

I get SQL Server linux container to run as service (I am guessing it is running). But I am not sure how I can load my database to it. I know I can do that using `Docker Run`. But I cannot figure it out how to run it here.

When I try to run "mssql-tools" as service I cannot get it's command to run as it is not install by default in dotnet image.

Here is my file.

> image: microsoft/dotnet:latest
>
> variables: 
>       ACCEPT_EULA: Y
>       SA_PASSWORD: my_secure_password
>       MSSQL_PID: Developer
>
> stages:
>       - test
>
> before_script:
>       - "cd Source"
>       - "dotnet restore"
>
> test:
>       stage: test
>       services:
>           - mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
>           - mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools
>       script:
>           - "cd ../Database"
>           - "docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools"
>           - "sqlcmd -S . -U SA -P my_secure_password -i testdata_structure.sql"
>           - "exit"
>           - "cd ../Source"
>           - "dotnet build"
>           - "dotnet test"

`"sqlcmd -S . -U SA -P my_secure_password -i testdata_structure.sql` this command won't work in this setup as sqlcmd is not installed, but is one of service. I don't want to make a new image that has all pre-install. But use available stuff to work.

Not, sure if I am able to explain my issue and knowledge here. I am new, but I am reading and changing configuration from 2 days. I can get Linux based SQL Server to run with my app from local docker commands and stuff, but on Gitlab to run Unit Test I cannot get database to restore/get running and connect to application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab Services does not install commands or apps inside your container job, instead a Service is another container that is usually run in parallel to offer infrastructure services such as databases, cache, queues, etc.

if you want to have sqlcmd inside your container you must install it:

This is an extract from my pipeline, in this case my container is based on Alpine but you can find more ways here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

```
 before_script: 
- apk add curl 
- apk add --no-cache gnupg
- curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.sig
- curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.7.1.1-1_amd64.sig
- curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.apk
- curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.7.1.1-1_amd64.apk
- curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc  | gpg --import -
- gpg --verify msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.sig msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.apk
- gpg --verify mssql-tools_17.7.1.1-1_amd64.sig mssql-tools_17.7.1.1-1_amd64.apk
- apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.apk
- apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools_17.7.1.1-1_amd64.apk

script: 
- /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S $DBC_SERVER -U $DBC_USER -P $DBC_PASSWORD -q "USE myTestDb; CREATE TABLE testGitlab (id int); SELECT * FROM testGitLab"
```

Comment: I have to thank you, that after 2 yrs at least someone try to answer it :).. Docker is never easy for me and I already learn it 2 months ago, but still not clear your script will surely help me moving forward with it.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using my custom Docker Image that has dotnetcore and Sqlcmd installed in it, I can use MsSQL Server as Service in gitlab configuration. (have to define SQL Server' hostname, as IP in same range as my server).

Not an idle answer, but workaround for me.